# Considered, expected in passive

Tags: meaning-in-context

Water is considered to be protected as scarcity of this is at peak. Considered is in correct here or not. Could there be two passive on one sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the last question first, it's okay to have two passives in a sentence: "The old house was believed to be haunted."

Is *considered* correct? It depends what you are trying to say. "John is considered to be a good driver" means "People think that John is a good driver." So you are saying "People think that water is protected..."

Is that what you mean? I'm not sure, because there are other problems with the sentence so it's hard to tell.

I would change "scarcity is at its peak". *Scarcity* is about the lack of something. *Peak* is exactly the opposite. (Peak supply is where supply is at
its highest.) I presume you are describing the highest level of scarcity. But the natural English form is to use an intensifying adverb: very scarce, or extremely scarce.

So I wonder if you just need to simplify the sentence: Water is protected because it is extremely scarce."

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with "water scarcity is at its peak" personally. We speak similarly of a "peak dry season."

Comment: Point taken. I didn't want to be dogmatic because as I said I'm not exactly sure what the OP is trying to say.

Comment: There is that. :)